# Can you put permissions on S3 file storage?

Tags: amazon-s3

Can you put permissions on files that are uploaded to S3?

Or if someone knows the guild/url to the file they can access it publicly?

If yes, what kind of permissions can we set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Permissions are implemented with a key mechanism.  You can make content readable for everyone (no password) or require a password.  You grant upload privileges by generating a keyed URI which you can limit to a maximum bandwidth.

[Amazon FAQ about access](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=1109&categoryID=55#06)

[Amazon documentation on authentication and access control](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/index.html?UsingAuthAccess.html)

As dcaunt states, [query string authentication](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/index.html?S3_QSAuth.html) requires an expiration date.

Answer (score 1):

Not passwords, but you can create links that expire on at a certain time: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/index.html?RESTAuthentication.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can also generate 'passwords' that are only valid for a certain period of time