# Saving Large file using GWT + GAE + S3 path

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, amazon-s3

I'm building app that will store large video files to the server and then user will be able to view them. For my app I'm using GWT + GAE/J and to store files I would like to use S3 account. But as we know that you can upload max 10mb to GAE. I have [asked this kind of question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067596/gwt-on-gae-and-s3) before and the answer that I have accepted will work only if you have file less then 10mb. That [solution](http://bizo-dev.blogspot.com/2009/05/google-app-engine-java-and-s3.html) that KevMo have suggested uploads whole files to the server but what if my file is 20mb or 100mb. Is it possible to divide that file into 10mb peaces, send them to GAE and then assemble those files on S3 server.
Here is the picture of what I'm trying to accomplish here:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not have your GWT client upload the video directly to S3?  You can have your app engine code create the authentication token or password or whatever S3 calls it, and then your GWT client would send the file straight there.  If need be, it could pass back whatever meta data that your app engine code needs.(file size, name, whatever)

see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719292/can-you-put-permissions-on-s3-file-storage) for more info on giving users permission to upload to S3:

PS - obviously this doesn't work quite as well if you are doing some kind of processing to the video in your app engine code before uploading it to S3[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/b49fdee149.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/b49fdee149.jpg)

Comment: No, I'm not going to do anything to those files, so it is fine to upload them as it to S3. Any suggestions what I can use to upload files straight to S3.

Comment: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/index.html?UsingHTTPPOST.html

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend developing your own transfer control instead. Likely it will take the same amount of time.

Comment: Can you elaborate this little bit more?